# Unable to import PrimeReact style files on Next.js project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, next.js, primereact

I'm trying to use PrimeReact components on a Next.js project but I'm getting an error when I try to import the core css styles as shows in their documentation (https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/setup), I have used these components with a create-react-app project, but this time I'm having the following error:
[Next js error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qKvo.jpg)

I'm using "@zeit/next-sass" and "node-sass" to work with SASS files, I read that is required to create a "webpack.config.js" to manually apply the right loaders but the problem persist (I'm not a webpack expert), I was wondering if someone can give me a hint of what I'm missing.

Thank you in advance.